# JavaScript: plugging behaviors into objects and easily removing those behaviors

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, rack

In JavaScript, I want to instantiate an object in a long-running application.  The object should allow itself to be augmented with mixins.  There are some design restrictions:

1. A mixin may override existing methods
2. A mixin may supply new methods
3. A given mixin method should be able to refer to the super thus allowing like-named behaviors spanning several mixins to be piped together
4. **It should be no harder to remove a mixin from the object than it was to add the mixin**
5. I want to push mixins into the object.  That is, I hope not to wrap/decorate the object as that outdates held references to the original object.

In JS normally mixins copy their methods directly onto an object.  This is fine if you don't want to easily unplug the new behavior.  The idea is that these behaviors should be easy to add or remove at any time since the application could be running indefinitely, and mucking with an object to add a behavior doesn't make removing it later neat and easy.

I am referring loosely to 'mixins'.  The main idea is that an object can plug or unplug behaviors that can be piped together; the mechanism itself is less important.  Some of you who may be familiar with [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack) know how useful this is.

```
var tim = new Person('Tim'); //at 12:00pm
tim.eat()                    //at 12:00pm -- native Person behavior
tim.addBehavior(husband)     //at 12:00pm
tim.kissWife()               //at 12:00pm -- husband behavior
tim.addBehavior(father)      //at 12:00pm
tim.addBehavior(hungry)      //at 12:00pm -- augments the native eat behavior
tim.addBehavior(bowler)      //at 5:00pm
tim.bowl()                   //at 5:00pm
tim.performDailyDuties()     //at 5:00pm -- includes husband and father duties
tim.removeBehavior(bowler)   //at 5:00pm -- easily remove behavior
tim.bowl()                   //at 5:01pm -- error!
tim.kissWife()               //at 5:01pm
```

I do not want to...

```
var husbandTim = new Husband(tim)
var bowlerTim  = new Bowler(husbandTim)
```

...because it makes it hard to remove one particular behavior.  Plus, what about all the places holding a reference to `tim`.  Those places won't be aware of the new behaviors.

Unfortunately, JS doesn't provide anything I'm aware of to make this easy.  ES6 will provide a Proxy which will allow for this, but I am wondering if I might have missed a simpler approach.

What design patterns or mechanisms might make it easy to add plugin behaviors that are just as easy to remove later?  Do any frameworks do something along these lines?

Answer (score 0):

I created an ES5 inheritance library a while ago called [Uberproto](http://daffl.github.io/uberproto/) that does allow you to add mixins to objects and call the overwritten method. For example:

```
var PersonObject = {
    init : function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },

    fullName : function() {
        return this.name;
    }
};

Proto.mixin({
    fullName : function() {
        return 'My name is: ' + this._super();
    }
}, PersonObject);

// Create a plain object without calling the constructor
var instance = Object.create(PersonObject);
instance.name = 'Dude';
console.log(instance.fullName()); // 'My name is: Dude'
```

I found it actually works quite well if you are careful what to create mixins for. I never needed to remove a mixin but it should be as easy as storing the reference to the original method before adding it:

```
var PersonObject = {
    init : function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },

    fullName : function() {
        return this.name;
    }
};

var backup = {
    fullName: PersonObject.fullName
};

Proto.mixin({
    fullName : function() {
        return 'My name is: ' + this._super();
    }
}, PersonObject);

// Create a plain object without calling the constructor
var instance = Object.create(PersonObject);
instance.name = 'Dude';
console.log(instance.fullName()); // 'My name is: Dude'

// Restore old mixin
PersonObject.fullName = backup.fullName;
var instance = Object.create(PersonObject);
instance.name = 'Dave';
console.log(instance.fullName()); // 'Dave'
```

So all you'd need to do is wrap that functionality into something more generic.

Comment: In most apps I've worked on being able to unplug a mixin hasn't been a serious need.  However, I do currently need this for one app.  Unfortunately, most languages don't make unmixing simple (they should).  JavaScript could easily accommodate this if instead of having a single prototype it allowed for multiple prototypes (multiple inheritance).  Will investigate your idea.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Doing unmixing in JS generically would be pretty hard at least in most implementations. You'd have to `.toString()` the function and then go up the `_super` chain to see if any matches. And then somehow rip it out of the chain. But if you have any ideas, I'd gladly consider adding it to the library. But like you said, I never ran into needing to remove it either.

Comment: I [prototyped this concept](https://gist.github.com/mlanza/5171432) using a Proxy and it works fine.  I just don't like that a Proxy was necessitated. The reason most apps don't need to unmix is that objects typically live only for a moment in order to accomplish work; not many objects are kept around long term.  Consider that roles we play are temporary.  When a person with husband behavior gets divorced that behavior should go away.